# no exported member 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES' in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
```

it gives an error `has no exported member 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES'`

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` member is deprecated since Angular 2.0.0 version. For new routing interface visit [ROUTING & NAVIGATION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Comment: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES member doesn't exist since Angular 2.0.0. What you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

ROUTER_DIRECTIVES member is deprecated

```
<a [routerLinks] ="['']"> home </a> |  <a [routerLinks] ="['/user']" > user </a>
```

Instead of

```
import { routing } from './app.routes';
```

routing is Import @ngModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule , routing],
  providers : [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

app.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active"> Home </a> |  <a routerLink="/user" > User </a>
```

Navigation by without reload page