# has no exported member 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES'. What its alternative?

Tags: javascript, angular

In component this line

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
```

gives an error

```
node_modules/@angular/common/index"' has no exported member 'FORM_DIRECTIVES'.
```

[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES member is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135209/no-exported-member-router-directives-in-angular2)

Is there any alternative of it?

Comment: As the error says. It's deprecated. Check the official docs for these kinds of things ;) Here's the doc for routing: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I follow https://plnkr.co/edit/YtJDZlA1mHtjA9ZmMHB3?p=preview for breadcrumbs

Comment: they use ROUTER_DIRECTIVES

Comment: Yes, but that is for version `Angular version: 2.0.0-rc.5` as it's stated in the plunker. You are (probably) using a newer version, and therefore it informs it's deprecated, as it is not used in newer versions. That's why I referred to the official documentation, as it's always up to date. You have to check your version of Angular and use the correct syntax for your version :)

Answer (score 2):

Import `RouterModule`  in your AppModule like this-

```
import { RouterModule }                 from '@angular/router';
```

and update it `@NgModule` like this-

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, RouterModule,
....
....
```

No need to import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in your component. The `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` member is deprecated since Angular Final 2.0.0 version.

Comment: and if import routes in component separately?

Comment: Do you mean navigating to component?

Comment: I follow plnkr.co/edit/YtJDZlA1mHtjA9ZmMHB3?p=preview for breadcrumbs

Comment: In it they use ROUTER_DIRECTIVES in app.component.ts

Comment: Plunker example uses `@2.0.0-rc.5` version which is very old and I think you are using Final 2.0.0 or above. Can you confirm your angular2 version?

Comment: read documentation from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) You dont need to use `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in `app.component.ts`. Instead use `RouterModule` using `AppModule` as mentioned in my answer.